# Configure hostname for next/image

Tags: node.js, next.js, nextjs-image

I am trying to upgrade my NextJS with `<Image />` from `next/image`. My images are hosted remotely. It seems that for remote images to work, I need to add my domain to the `next.config.js`.

I did it as below:

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  '@maxmind/geoip2-node',
  'amp-html',
  'lodash-es',
]); // pass the modules you would like to see transpiled
const withImages = require('next-images');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { uniq } = require('lodash');
const makeWithbundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer');
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withSourceMaps = require('@zeit/next-source-maps');

const { assetBaseUrl } = require('./lib/AssetHelper');
const { env: environmentVariables } = require('./app.json');

// Set env vars before running webpack
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
  require('dotenv-flow').config();
}

module.exports = {
  analyticsId: analyticsId,
};

const withBundleAnalyzer = makeWithbundleAnalyzer({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
});

// For all env vars required by the app:
// - throw an error if required but not set in env
// - serialize  non-sensitive env vars where sensitive flag is set
function serializeEnvVariables() {
  return Object.entries(environmentVariables).reduce(
    (hash, [key, { serialize }]) => {
      const value = process.env[key];

      if (serialize) {
        return { ...hash, [key]: JSON.stringify(value) };
      }

      return hash;
    },
    {}
  );
}

const securityHeaders = [
  {
    key: 'referrer-policy',
    value: 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
  },
  {
    key: 'x-content-type-options',
    value: 'nosniff',
  },
  {
    key: 'x-download-options',
    value: 'noopen',
  },
  {
    key: 'x-frame-options',
    value: 'SAMEORIGIN',
  },
  {
    key: 'x-permitted-cross-domain-policies',
    value: 'none',
  },
  {
    key: 'x-xss-protection',
    value: '1; mode=block',
  },
];

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [withBundleAnalyzer, withImages, withSourceMaps, withTM],
  {
    // Append the domain where the assets are hosted
    assetPrefix: assetBaseUrl(),

    images: {
      domains: ['static.mydomain.com'],
      disableStaticImages: true,
    },

    i18n: {
      locales: ['en', 'es'],
      defaultLocale: 'en',
    },

    async headers() {
      return [
        {
          source: '/:path*',
          headers: securityHeaders,
        },
      ];
    },

    async redirects() {
      return [
        {
          source: '/consumer-guides/:path*',
          destination: '/guides/:path*',
          permanent: true,
        },
      ];
    },

    // Customize webpack config for next.js
    // _config is the default next.js webpack configuration
    webpack(_config, { isServer }) {
      // Reassign to allow changes and appease linter
      const config = _config;
      const oldEntry = config.entry;

      let remoteConfigFile;

      // currently, firebase-admin will blow up if so much as imported on the
      // client
      if (process.env.INTEGRATION_TESTING) {
        remoteConfigFile = './integrationTestRemoteConfig';
      } else if (isServer) {
        remoteConfigFile = './serverSideRemoteConfig';
      } else {
        remoteConfigFile = './standardRemoteConfig';
      }

      config.resolve.alias = {
        // Sentry requires different packages for front and back end,
        // so use an alias that will automatically choose the correct
        // version
        'sentry-alias': isServer ? '@sentry/node' : '@sentry/browser',
        '@/remoteConfig': remoteConfigFile,
        ...config.resolve.alias,
      };

      config.externals.push('fs', 'net');

      // Fill in process.env on the client
      config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.serializedEnv': serializeEnvVariables(),
        })
      );

      // It seems like there should be some way to get the next
      // static folder, but I can't find anywhere it's configured
      // by next, seems to just be hardcoded.
      config.output.publicPath = `${this.assetPrefix}/_next/`;

      // Add new rules to previous rules
      config.module.rules.push(
        // Allow us to import markdown files
        {
          test: /\.md$/,
          loader: 'raw-loader',
        },
        {
          resolve: { mainFields: ['module', 'main'] },
        },
        // temporary fix for when process is undefined with react-markdown: https://github.com/vfile/vfile/issues/38#issuecomment-683198538
        // perm fix, see: https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/178868237
        {
          test: /node_modules\/vfile\/core\.js/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'imports-loader',
              options: {
                type: 'commonjs',
                imports: ['single process/browser process'],
              },
            },
          ],
        }
      );

      config.entry = async function entry() {
        const entries = await oldEntry();

        // Add our customer initializers before any other code
        if (entries['main.js']) {
          // NOTE: these are only included in the client bundle, if you want
          // something added on the server you must import it in server.js
          entries['main.js'].unshift('./configs/initialize/index.js');
          entries['main.js'] = uniq(entries['main.js']);
        }

        return entries;
      };

      return config;
    },
  }
);
```

However, it is not working for me. I am getting an error:

```
Error: Invalid src prop (https://static.mydomain.com/images/forsale/2020/03/19/01/16/my_item_for_sale.jpeg) on `next/image`, hostname "static.mydomain.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is not `domains: ['static.mydomain.com']` allowing me to use the urls starting with 'static.mydomain.com'?

Comment: Try removing the first `module.exports`. Add `analyticsId: analyticsId` to the config object below if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions that might resolve your problem. Add all formats of files that you try to import:

```
images: {
    domains: ['static.mydomain.com'],
    formats: ['image/jpeg'],
},
```

Or remove `disableStaticImages: true`, because it dissallows you to import static files as `src` property.